# RDLC merge cells under a group

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am using two groups for the first two columns (Date, Name). The next two colums (Test Name, Total) will always be unique regarding to each group. But the last column (Total) has duplicate values. I want to merge those into a single cell. How can I do that?

[image]